# How to generate JPA mappings with IntelliJ without persistence units?

Tags: java, jpa, intellij-idea, orm, spring-data-jpa

How to generate JPA mappings with IntelliJ?

Apparently, `IntelliJ` requires me to describe `JPA facet`, while `JPA facet` requires me to create persistence units, which are not actually required by my code.

Is it possible to generate JPA mappings without describing all this glitching stuff?

Comment: Which idea version are you using and what does your configuration look like? There was a [bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-124673) in idea 13.x version. Normaly idea should pick up the persistence unit from your spring configuration.

Comment: I don't have any Spring configuration either. I am trying to use Spring-Boot, it pretends to work without configuration. My IntelliJ is 15.x, also I tried to use 2016.x and latter looked even worse.

Comment: Does the description of this [bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-151230) relate to your setup?

Comment: Yes, I think so. I was to downgrade from 2016 to avoid this. They apparently made some mess with new module structure, which is incompatible with many plugins like spring boot.

Comment: Why don't you just create the jpa persistence unit files, use it to generate the mappings, then delete them again (or, keep them for later just in case you need to regenerate the mappings again)? The persistence unit files are only a few lines long and aren't hard to write really. I know its not the best answer, but it gets you past the problem with IntelliJ.